# Forcing specific resolution on a specific monitor on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6) installed with 2 monitors.

Main: a 24 inch Dell monitor that Mac OS X detects and displays on 1920x1200

Secondary: a 19 inch Chimei monitor that supports resolution 1440x900 but Mac OS X detects it as 1344x1008.

How can I force a 1400x900 resolution on my secondary monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at SwitchResX - did it for me, fixing some frequency issues with my crappy Acer display.